# Add LazyRow or scrollable Row without increasing the width of parent

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I want to add a `LazyRow` to a `Column` that doesn't have a width specified. (usually I would just do `.fillMaxWidth()` but I want the width to depend on the content)

[image]

The problem is that it increases the width of the column.

```
@Composable
fun Test() {
    val items = listOf("Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4")
    
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.background(Color.Yellow)
    ) {
        Text("Title", style = MaterialTheme.typography.titleLarge)
        LazyRow {
            items(items){
                Text(text = it)
            }
        }
    }
}

@Preview
@Composable
fun TestPreview() {
    Test()
}
```

Is it possible to get what the width of the `Column` would be if the `LazyRow` wasn't there?

Edit: Similar to `Slider` in `DropdownMenu`

[image: long slider]

[image: short slider]

[image: items]

```
@Composable
fun Test() {
    val items = listOf("Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4")
    var expanded by remember {
        mutableStateOf(false)
    }

    Box {
        Button(onClick = { expanded = true}) {
            Text(text = "Open dropdown")
        }

        DropdownMenu(
            modifier = Modifier
                .heightIn(max = 200.dp),
            expanded = expanded,
            onDismissRequest = { expanded = false })
        {
            Column {
                Text("Short text", style = MaterialTheme.typography.titleLarge)
                Slider(value = 0.5f, onValueChange = {})
                Row(
                    modifier = Modifier.horizontalScroll(rememberScrollState())
                ) {
                    items.forEach {
                        Text(text = it)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't quite get you, do you want the `LazyRow` to fit the width of the screen & not expand (scroll horizontally)? like the behavior of `match_parent`.

Comment: @Vishnu I want the `LazyRow` to have a fixed width and to scroll horizontally to see more items. I want that width to be the width the `Column` would have if the row wasn't there, or to put it another way, I want the `Column` to ignore the row when calculating its width. (similar to `Slider`, see edit)

Comment: You always want `LazyRow` to be as wide as Text is or at most 100.dp or another width instead of `LazyRow` being as wide as its content, right?

Comment: @Thracian Indeed, but a small correction: I want it to be exactly the width of the text (content of the `Column`). The `Modifier.width(100.dp)` was just to illustrate where I would put `.width(widthOfContentWithoutRow)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give a static value to your width and then the lazy row will be placed inside the given width. In case it should work dynamically, try using the below method.

```
@Composable
fun AlignTextAndLazyRow() {
Column(modifier = Modifier.wrapContentSize()
    .background(Color.Gray) //to check container size
) {

    Layout(content = {
        Text(text = "Your text here", Modifier.layoutId("text"))
        LazyRow(
            modifier = Modifier.wrapContentWidth().layoutId("row")
        ) {
            items(10) {
                Text(text = "Hello")
            }
        }
    }, measurePolicy = { measurables, constraints ->
        val textPlaceable = measurables.first { it.layoutId == "text" }.measure(constraints)

        val rowPlaceable = measurables.first { it.layoutId == "row" }.measure(
            constraints.copy(maxWidth = textPlaceable.width)
        )
        val offset = 10 //min offset

        val containerWidth = textPlaceable.width
        val height = textPlaceable.height + rowPlaceable.height + offset

        layout(containerWidth, height) {
            rowPlaceable.placeRelative(0, textPlaceable.height + offset)
            textPlaceable.placeRelative(0, 0)
        }
    })
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just set the width of the `Column` instead and then `LazyRow` automatically fit inside it. Like:

```
@Composable
fun Test() {
    val items = listOf("Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4")

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .background(Color.Yellow)
            .width(100.dp) // Set width here
    ) {
        Text(
            "Title",
            style = MaterialTheme.typography.titleLarge
        )
        LazyRow(
            modifier = Modifier
        ) {
            items(items) {
                Text(text = it)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The issue is that if "Title" is longer in another language, it will be split into 2 lines. Therefore, I am reluctant to use hardcoded values.

Comment: @BPDev Then you should use `textOverflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis` and `maxLines = 1` to avoid covering more than one line in `Text` composable. Apart from that you can also use `MarqueeText` to make text moving.